# How can I remove format warning in c language?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void) { 
  int *pVar, var = 10;
  pVar = &var;
  //*pVar = var; 

  printf("value = %d, address = Ox%X\n", var, &var);    
  // Format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'int *' 
  
  printf("pValue = %d, address = Ox%X\n", *pVar, pVar);
  // Format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'int *' 

  *pVar = 20; 

  printf("value = %d, address = Ox%X\n", var, &var);
  // Format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'int *' 

  printf("pValue = %d, address = Ox%X\n", *pVar, pVar);
  // Format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'int *' 

  return 0; 
}
```

I find some warning

Format specifies type `unsigned int` but the argument has type `int *`

> Even though the program runs as I intend, I want to know why this happen.
>
> What should I do to remove those errors without making some errors in result?

Comment: Please post the code in text format over here.

Comment: @SouravGhosh What does 'UB' mean?

Comment: @Kotshi undefined behavior.

Comment: Next time, post text.  Could use http://www.onlineocr.net to make your picture text.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `%p` format for pointers as in

```
printf("value = %d, address = %p\n", var, (void *) &var);
```

Comment: A cast: `(void *)&var` is required for `%p`.